# Setting image on tabbar items in special case(if tab bar taken on viewController)

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am taking tab bar controller on view controller rather than delegate, and used code what mentioned below.

```
tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
tabController.delegate = self;

scanView = [[ScanTicketView alloc] init];
searchView = [[SearchView alloc] init];
historyView = [[HistoryView alloc]init];

tabController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:scanView,searchView,historyView, nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabController animated:YES];
```

It works, but now how to apply images to these views. Can anyone help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
 viewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
```

if you want to apply the image only to selected view controller in Tab bar, then UITabBarController has a selectedViewController and a selectedIndex property also see tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.tag if this may help.

Answer (score 1):

Tabbar controller has its own property of Image and Title.

Go through this [UITabbar Tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iPhone-TabBar-Application-Tutorial-UITabBar.html) to understand properly. You can set image through property window or even through coding also.

Best Luck !